# How to reference a process reliably (using a tag or something similar)?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows

I have multiple processes (web-scrapers) running in the background (one scraper for each website). The processes are python scripts that were spawned/forked a few weeks ago. I would like to control (they listen on sockets to enable IPC) them from one central place (kinda like a dispatcher/manager python script), while the processes (scrapers) remain individual unrelated processes.

I thought about using the PID to reference each process, but that would require storing the PID whenever I (re)launch one of the scrapers because there is no semantic relation between a number and my use case. I just want to supply some text-tag along with the process when I launch it, so that I can reference it later on.

Comment: @SamBob solution works for Linux. In case anyone interested in Windows cmd refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program) answer. For powershell the following command can be used: `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Select-Object CommandLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgrep -f` searches all processes by their name and calling pattern (including arguments).

E.g. if you spawned a process as `python myscraper --scrapernametag=uniqueid01`  then you can run:

`TAG=uniqueid01; pgrep -f "scrapernametag=$TAG"`

to discover the PID of a process later down the line.

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of completeness: It also works well work me using `ps a`